# JS: Получить все ключи с localStorage которые начинаются со слов массива

Tags: javascript, массивы, localstorage

Как известно чтобы получить ключи всех записей localStorage которые начинаются с какого то одного определённого слова можно использовать код:

```
for (i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
    var myKey = localStorage.key(i);
    if(myKey.slice(0,7) === 'myWord0') {
        console.log(myKey);
    }
}
```

Но как быть если нужно получить ключи всех записей, которые начинаются не с какого то ОДНОГО определённого слова а со слов определённого массива? При этом длина каждого слова в массиве одинаковая например 7 символов

```
var arrayOfMyWords = ["myWord1","myWord2","myWord3"];
```

Comment: [startsWith](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) метод поможет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для проверки того, что строка начинается с подстроки, можно использовать [`startsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) либо [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf). При использовании этих функций не важна длина проверяемой строки.

Для проверки, что начинается с хотя бы одного слова из массива - [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Например:

```
var arrayOfMyWords = ["myWord1","myWord2","myWord3"];
for (i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
    var myKey = localStorage.key(i);
    if(arrayOfMyWords.some(function(word){ return myKey.indexOf(word) === 0})) {
        console.log(myKey);
    }
}
```